# Multiple timer with different interval in C#.net

Tags: c#

I want different timer with different interval that i input.For example, if I input 4, 4 timer create and show time in 4 label, where 1st timer's time change in 1sec,2nd timer's time change in 2sec,3rd timer's time change in 3sec and 4tn timer's time change in 4sec.Here is my code,

```
        string input = textBox2.Text;
        int n = Convert.ToInt32(input);
        for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {

            Timer timer = new Timer();
            timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick); 
            timer.Interval = (1000) * (i);              


            timer.Enabled = true;                      
            timer.Start();                            



            Label label = new Label();               
            label.Name = "label"+i;
            label.Location = new Point(100, 100 + i * 30);
            label.TabIndex = i;
            label.Visible = true;


            this.Controls.Add(label);

        }
     private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

             label.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();


         }
```

But i don't get any output.What can i do.I use windows application.

Comment: Please specify exactly *which* Timer class is being used (the fully qualified). There are so many of them that act ever so slightly differently.

Comment: I don't see how this can compile, does it not give an error on `label` use in `timer_Tick`?

Comment: @Hernal Pandya The joys of shadowing ;-)

Comment: The other way, than Bala R shown to you is keep reference of variable in a dictionary (dict) for timer and label pairs, and access in event handler by sender reference: Timer t = (Timer)sender; dict[t].Text = string.Format("{0:00}{1:00}", t.Hours,t.Seconds);

Comment: @Hernal Pandya: in a post, i is not initialized, create declaration for i first, than put on a clean form 2 text boxes and one button, put code below in a Click event handler (double click on a button in designer view), and add code for timer event handler to form class, then think how you can connect these things together ;)

Comment: what will be the string format if i want to include some text with datetime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other way, than Bala R shown to you is keep reference of variable in a dictionary (dict) for timer and label pairs, and access in event handler by sender reference (Full source code, with 2 text boxes ans a button, 2nd textbox contains text "3"), hope it will help:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ProjectDocumentationWorkspace.UI
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        private Dictionary<Timer, Label> dict = new Dictionary<Timer, Label>();

        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void CreateTimers()
        {
            string input = textBox2.Text;
            int n = Convert.ToInt32(input);
            for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            {

                Timer timer = new Timer();
                timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
                timer.Interval = (1000) * (i);

                Label label = new Label();
                label.Name = "label" + i;
                label.Location = new Point(100, 100 + i * 30);
                label.TabIndex = i;
                label.Visible = true;

                this.Controls.Add(label);

                dict[timer] = label;

                timer.Enabled = true;
                timer.Start();
            }
        }

        private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Timer t = (Timer)sender;
            DateTime current = DateTime.Now;
            dict[t].Text = string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", current.Hour, current.Minute, current.Second);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CreateTimers();
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: what will be the string format if i want to include some text with datetime?

Comment: how can i use Dictionary<ThreadingTimer, Label> @artur?Can u Help me?

Answer (score 2):

I don't see how the Timer's Tick event handler can access a dynamic label that's not in it's scope.

Try

```
        Label label = new Label();               
        label.Name = "label"+i;
        label.Location = new Point(100, 100 + i * 30);
        label.TabIndex = i;
        label.Visible = true;

        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.Tick += (s, e) => label.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        timer.Interval = (1000) * (i);              


        timer.Enabled = true;                      
        timer.Start();
```

Another alternative is to have a `Dictionary<Timer, Label>` and add controls to this dictionary as they are created and in the timer's tick handler use the dictionary to retrieve its corresponding `Label`

Comment: you probably need to Invoke text change on UI thread for that to work

Comment: +1, capturing the local variable by reference in C# (Label instance) will actually work.

Comment: @Valentin isn't System.Forms.Timer's Tick always on UI thread?

Comment: I dont understand that line, timer.Tick += (s, e) => label.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();

Comment: @sumona: See my simplified version and compare to your orignal post. Hope it will helps

Comment: hm thats interesting, I was thinking since we got multiple timers we are using System.Timers.Timer which fires events on thread pool, nevermind then

Comment: @Bala R: Why you duplicate my answer in yours? It looks stupid, actually

Comment: @Arthur can you see that my answer is from 04:11:13 and your's is from 04:25:10 and I have no edits. I had it 14mins sooner than you did. I had that suggestion in my answer all along. You must have missed it.